# How can I test a method call inside an asynchronous operation in unit testing

Tags: java, asynchronous, mockito, junit5, completable-future

I have a method that first performs a series of actions, after which it starts an asynchronous task. I want to test this method, but I don’t understand how I can verify that the asynchronous operation has completed.

Using Moсkito, I want to verify that the *foo* method was executed 2 times, once before the start of the asynchronous task and once inside it. The problem is that at the time of the Mockito check the asynchronous task might not yet call the method inside the asynchronous operation. Therefore, the test is sometimes performed, and sometimes not.

This is the example of my method:

```
void testingMethod() {
    // some operations
    someObject.foo();
    CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
        // some other operations
        someObject.foo();
    });
}
```

And example of my test where someObject is mocked:

```
@Test
public void testingMethodTest() {
    testObject.testingMethod();

    Mockito.verify(someObject, Mockito.times(2)).foo();
}
```

Is there a way to wait for an asynchronous operation to complete before the verify method. Or is this a bad way to test and what can you advise in this case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can have a `TimeUnit.SECONDS.sleep(1);` after `testObject.testingMethod();` in your test.

On a side note, I dont even think you should test that what happens asynchronously is completed or called or whatever, its not responsibility of this function.

Comment: Is that a good way to sleep? Because it is just waiting for a certain amount of time, but asynchronous operations may not be performed yet. I also want to explain why the method has such a structure: first the basic operations take place, after which the main code can continue to execute, but I also need to perform a number of rather long tasks that are needed, but not necessary for the main code. Therefore, this is done to speed up the main code. Nevertheless, this is an important part of the method that applies to it, and I also want to test the fact that these actions are performed.

Comment: With your current code, there's no way to know for sure. because you're doing whats called a "fire and forget". You dont care about when async block is executed as long as its executed. If you care that it is, you can wait for it in your method, do something like validate everything went well during the async part. That will make your method finish *only* when that async code is done, and thus making it fully testable.

Comment: Ok, I get it, thanks for the help. Maybe I should return future from this method, this will allow me to call *get()* in the test and check the method call.

Answer (score 5):

The problem boils down to to the fact that the tested method calls a static method: `CompletableFuture.runAsync()`. Static methods in general give little control for mocking and asserting.

Even if you use a `sleep()` in your test, you cannot assert whether `someObject.foo()` is called asynchronously or not. If the call is made on the calling thread, the test will still pass. Moreover using `sleep()` slows down your tests, and a too short `sleep()` will cause the test to randomly fail.

If really this seems to be the only solution, you should use a library like [Awaitability](https://github.com/awaitility/awaitility/wiki/Usage#simple) that polls until the assertion is satisfied, with a timeout.

**There are several alternatives to make your code easier to test:**

1. **Make `testingMethod()` return a `Future`** (as you thought in the comments): this does not allow asserting the asynchronous execution, but it avoids waiting too much;
2. **Wrap the `runAsync()` method in another service** that you can mock, and capture the argument;
3. **If you are using Spring**, move the lambda expression to another service, in a method annotated with `@Async`. This allows to easily mock and unit test that service, and removes the burden of calling `runAsync()` directly;
4. **Use a custom executor**, and pass it to `runAsync()`;

If you are using Spring, **I would recommend using the third solution** as it really is the cleanest, and avoids cluttering your code with `runAsync()` calls everywhere.

Options 2 and 4 are very similar, it just changes what you have to mock.

**If you go for the fourth solution, here is how you can do it:**

Change tested class to use a custom `Executor`:

```
class TestedObject {
    private SomeObject someObject;
    private Executor executor;

    public TestedObject(SomeObject someObject, Executor executor) {
        this.someObject = someObject;
        this.executor = executor;
    }

    void testingMethod() {
        // some operations
        someObject.foo();
        CompletableFuture.runAsync(() -> {
            // some other operations
            someObject.foo();
        }, executor);
    }
}
```

Implement a custom `Executor` that simply captures the command instead of running it:

```
class CapturingExecutor implements Executor {

    private Runnable command;

    @Override
    public void execute(Runnable command) {
        this.command = command;
    }

    public Runnable getCommand() {
        return command;
    }
}
```

(you could also `@Mock` the `Executor` and use an `ArgumentCaptor` but I think this approach is cleaner)

Use the `CapturingExecutor` in your test:

```
@RunWith(MockitoJUnitRunner.class)
public class TestedObjectTest {
    @Mock
    private SomeObject someObject;

    private CapturingExecutor executor;

    private TestedObject testObject;

    @Before
    public void before() {
        executor = new CapturingExecutor();
        testObject = new TestedObject(someObject, executor);
    }

    @Test
    public void testingMethodTest() {
        testObject.testingMethod();

        verify(someObject).foo();
        // make sure that we actually captured some command
        assertNotNull(executor.getCommand());

        // now actually run the command and check that it does what it is expected to do
        executor.getCommand().run();
        // Mockito still counts the previous call, hence the times(2).
        // Not relevant if the lambda actually calls a different method.
        verify(someObject, times(2)).foo();
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I have already solved the my problem by returning the Future (your first suggestion). This solved my problem. I'm interested in your third suggestion, I will try it later.

Answer (score 3):

For those you are looking for more suggestions in this topic, please try out `Mockito.timeout()` function as it is specifically meant to test async methods.

Example:

```
verify(mockedObject,timeout(100).times(1)).yourMethod();
```

also there is one more method called `after()`. It is also useful.

https://www.javadoc.io/doc/org.mockito/mockito-core/2.2.9/org/mockito/verification/VerificationWithTimeout.html